# Error al cargar ruta de imagen (Sqlite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Selecciono una imagen de la galería y guardo la ruta en `Sqlite` y hasta ahí todo bien, el problema viene cuando intentando cargar la imagen, se muestra  `ImageView` vacío y en `Logcat` recibo por dos veces:

> Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Dejar claro que en `Manifest` tengo los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Y en la aplicación tengo los permisos concedidos.

El código cuando intento cargar la imagen:

```
  private String ruta_imagen = "";

// obtengo todo lo demás correctamente, menos la imagen:

     if (notas != null) {
            ed_titulo.setText(notas.getTitulo());
            ed_nota.setText(notas.getNotas());
            tv_fecha.setText(notas.getFecha());
            tv_persistente.setText(notas.getPersistente());
            tv_categoria.setText(notas.getCategoria());
            image1.setImageBitmap(crearThumb());
        }

  private Bitmap getBitmap(String ruta_imagen) {
        // Objetos.
        File imagenArchivo = new File(ruta_imagen);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if (imagenArchivo.exists()) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagenArchivo.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap crearThumb(){
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(ruta_imagen);
        BitmapFactory.Options opciones = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opciones.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ruta_imagen, opciones);

        int scaleW = opciones.outWidth / 854 + 1;
        int scaleH = opciones.outHeight / 480 + 1;
        int scale = Math.max(scaleW, scaleH);

        opciones.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        opciones.inSampleSize = scale;
        opciones.inSampleSize = scale;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ruta_imagen, opciones);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es debido a que simplemente no encuentra el archivo o no existe:

> Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed:
>   ENOENT (No such file or directory)

No estas inicializando la variable `ruta_imagen` por lo tanto no puede encontrar un archivo.

Comment: No me di cuenta! Gracias @Jorgesys :)

Comment: Hehe  saludos!